# How can I set all columns' default value equal to null in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, default-value, information-schema

I would like to set the default value for every column in a number of tables equal to Null. I can view the default constraint under information_schema.columns.column_default. When I try to run 
    `update information_schema.columns set column_default = Null where table_name = '[table]'`
it throws "ERROR:  cannot update a view HINT:  You need an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule."

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run an `ALTER TABLE` statement for each column. Never ever try to do something like that by manipulating system tables (even if you find the correct one - INFORMATION_SCHEMA only contains view to the real system tables)

But you can generate all needed `ALTER TABLE` statements based on the data in the information_schema views:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||table_name||' ALTER COLUMN '||column_name||' SET DEFAULT NULL;'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'foo';
```

Save the output as a SQL script and then run that script (don't forget to commit the changes)